# Renaming files via script

Tags: vbscript

This script below renames a group of images run by a scheduled task, in which the live one becomes the wallpaper for the week (from the best of my knowledge).
The script hasn't worked in some time, no environment change. My VB is a little rusty, but I can't seem to see the issue.

Error message:

[image]

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFldr = fso.getfolder("E:\Users\Citrix Templates\Wallpaper")
For Each ofile In oFldr.Files
  If ofile.Name = "1.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "b0.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "2.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "1.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "3.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "2.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "4.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "3.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "5.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "4.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "6.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "5.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "7.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "6.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "8.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "7.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "9.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "8.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a0.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "9.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a1.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a0.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a2.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a1.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a3.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a2.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a4.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a3.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a5.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a4.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a6.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a5.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a7.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a6.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a8.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a7.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "a9.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a8.jpg"
  ElseIf ofile.Name = "LiveCitrixWallpaper.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "a9.jpg"
  End If
Next

For Each ofile In oFldr.Files
  If ofile.Name = "b0.jpg" Then
    ofile.Name = "LiveCitrixWallpaper.jpg"
  End If
Next
```

Comment: You are probably trying to rename a file to a file name that already exists. For example if file `LiveCitrixWallpaper.jpg` exists and you try and rename something to that, I guess it would throw that error. Has the script ever worked?

Comment: If I count to line 14, the code is this: `ofile.Name = "4.jpg"`. Go crack open the folder and see if that file exists. If so, delete it and run again. I guess you'll get the error on a different line.

Comment: can confirm, it was working as some point.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the image b0.jpg  from the file path and it seems to be working.

Not sure as to why it was breaking it... but its renaming them now.

Comment: since the script maintains a round robin list, you should check if b0 exists at the beginning and delete it. For clarity I'd change all the `elseif` to `if` and put the `ofile.Name = "1.jpg"` behind `Then`